# Amazon SageMaker could not find a valid Conda environment file

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I've been running Amazon SageMaker lab.
I opened SageMaker Studio Lab example notebooks, AWS Machine Learning University.
Every lab gave the error mesasge: `No Conda environment file found Could not find a valid Conda environment file. Please check to make sure you have provided a valid path and filename`.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The yml file is at `~/sagemaker-studiolab-notebooks/aws-machine-learning-university-accelerated-tab/mlu-tab.yml`

To run with the mlu-tab environment:

1. Open the Terminal from `File > New > Terminal`.
2. Change your working directory to aws-machine-learning-university-accelerated-tab, by run the script in the terminal:
   `cd sagemaker-studiolab-notebooks/aws-machine-learning-university-accelerated-tab`
3. In the Terminal, run the installation command to launch the environment: `conda env create -f mlu-tab.yml`
4. After the installation, you can active the environment with `conda activate mlu-tab`
5. The kernel might need to be restarted as well

Reference:

- [Now in Preview – Amazon SageMaker Studio Lab, a Free Service to Learn and Experiment with ML](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/now-in-preview-amazon-sagemaker-studio-lab-a-free-service-to-learn-and-experiment-with-ml/)
- [Getting started with Amazon SageMaker Studio Lab](https://medium.com/@ioan_portal/getting-started-with-amazon-sagemaker-studio-lab-4c0fab98f4b3)

Comment: Hi Mia, Thank you for your information!! it was fixed;)